# Where is my kedro output when using the databricks extension in vscode

Tags: azure, visual-studio-code, databricks, kedro

I am using kedro together with the databricks extension for vscode to access databricks server on Azure.
Everything works pretty well but I don't see any output when executing the file locally.
The only output I receive is:

```
31/03/2023, 15:09:32 - Synchronizing code to /Repos/<>@<>.ide ...
31/03/2023, 15:09:32 - Running kedro-hello-world.py ...

[03/31/23 13:09:37] INFO     Kedro project dp-kedro                                                  session.py:355
31/03/2023, 15:09:43 - Done (took 13914ms)
```

If i look at the logs i see the following:

```json
{
    "level": "debug",
    "logger": "SDK",
    "loggingFunction": "CommandExecutionService.commandStatus",
    "message": "cluster",
    "operationId": "id",
    "operationName": "CommandExecutionService.commandStatus",
    "request": {"method": "GET"},
    "response": {
        "id": "id",
        "results": {
            "data": "[03/31/23 12:41:43] INFO     Kedro project dp-kedro                                                  session.py:355",
            "resultType": "text",
        },
        "status": "Finished",
    },
    "timestamp": 1680266509470,
}
```

So it seems that the rest of the messages arent coming back to vscode?
Executing the file directly on databricks works and I can see all outputs of Kedro.

Comment: Hi! Can I ask you how did you setup vscode and databricks to run kedro with that extension?

Comment: @DanielPerezEfremova I used the databricks extension in vscode. No specific setup, and then I used a standard Kedro run python script.

Comment: And how did you deal with dependencies. Let is suppose you need tensorlfow in your pipeline. Would you install tensorflow manually in the compute instance?

Comment: I didn't do it manually, i used databricks with pypi (https://docs.databricks.com/en/libraries/package-repositories.html#pypi-libraries). Then the packages get installed when the cluster starts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So logging configuration in Kedro is done within the [logging.yml][1] file which points to the Python `logging.dictConfig` method 1:1

I haven't had a chance to use the new databricks extension myself, perhaps the [verbose mode](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/vscode-ext.html) here is useful?

---

As discovered in the thread below -

> I've finally found it, because I am working through vscode -> databricks -> kedro, the logging (which is using rich) is messed up, removing rich from the config and replace it by console works... so the initial tip of looking into logging works :) thx

Please set your `logging.yml` to plain console logging and remove the `RichHandler`

```
 root:
-  handlers: [rich, info_file_handler, error_file_handler]
+  handlers: [console, info_file_handler, error_file_handler]
```

Comment: Yes I've already tried both options but unfortunately with no success.
It seems like the API of databricks returns limited information or only the first output of the result.

Comment: I've finally found it, because I am working through vscode -> databricks -> kedro, the logging (which is using `rich`) is messed up, removing rich from the config and replace it by console works... so the initial tip of looking into logging works :) thx

Comment: This is really helpful @yoniprv we will add this to the docs!